# What's golang's equivalent to PHP's unpack(“f”, $str)?

Tags: php, go

I want to convert hexadecimal to float using golang,but i did not get the correct result.

PHP have an unpack function which can get the correct result.

#### Golang code

```
i := "CDC1933E"
b, _ := hex.DecodeString(i)
buf := bytes.NewReader(b)
var f float32
err := binary.Read(buf, binary.BigEndian, &f)
fmt.Println(f)
```

#### PHP code

```
var_dump(unpack("f",hex2bin("CDC1933E")));
```

The correct result shoud be 0.28858796.

Comment: I tried some online hex-to-float converter, and 0.28858796 is not the correct answer. the correct float number should be -4.05957e+08. and your go code is generating valid answer

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you the result you are expecting ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bTkJAurhfsH)):

```
i := "CDC1933E"
b, _ := hex.DecodeString(i)
buf := bytes.NewReader(b)
var ui uint32
err := binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, &ui)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
f := math.Float32frombits(ui)
fmt.Println(f)
```

You will note that the data is little endian encoded (Python defaults to the byte order of your host system; assuming you are running intel x86/AMD64  that is little-endian).